# QT creator on mac leaves hanging terminal windows after each launch

Tags: macos, qt, qt-creator

I'm using qt creator on mac as an IDE for cmake project (no qt lib is used). Each time I fire up debug or run it creates a terminal window. Those windows are not closed after the program finishes, instead they just accumulate.

Environment: Mac Os 11.2.3, Qt 5.15.2, Qt Creator 4.14.0

Any help on how do I make It either close automatically or, ideally, never appear and use just embedded qt creator output facilities is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure what output to use in the run settings. Go to projects (on the left) -> run (for your currently selected kit) -> uncheck "run in terminal".

[image]